# Extract value based on column header from Comma separated file using bash

Tags: linux, csv, text-processing

I want to extract 1st value from a csv for a specific column name using bash. For example, i want to extract first value of column "`bb`". Columns can be in any order

```
aa,bb,cc
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The output should be `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',' 'NR == 1{ for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "bb") { pos = i; break } }
           NR == 2{ print $pos; exit }' file.csv
```

The output:

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this using [csvkit](/questions/tagged/csvkit) :

```
csvcut -c 2 file.csv | awk 'NR==2'
```

### Output :

```
2
```